# RESTEasy with Guice InstantiationError at deployment (App Engine local)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice, resteasy

I am trying to get Guice to work with RESTEasy by following the instructions here: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.21.Final/userguide/html/Guice1.html

However, there is an error `InstantiationError` on `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment` during deployment on App Engine (local deployment):

```
2019-11-12 21:01:15.419:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@557a1e2d{APP,/,file:///PATH/target/APP-1.0-SNAPSHOT/,UNAVAILABLE}{PATH\target\APP-1.0-SNAPSHOT}
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap.<init>(ConfigurationBootstrap.java:21)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ListenerBootstrap.<init>(ListenerBootstrap.java:25)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:23)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:957)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:922)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:343)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:283)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:223)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:404)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
```

I reversed my changes and found that merely adding the following dependency in my pom.xml causes the deployment error.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

If I remove it, the deployment has no errors. Any idea why this happens? The other RESTEasy- and Guice-related dependencies are declared:

```
    <!--RESTEasy Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Guice -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got past the error by setting `resteasy-guice` dependency version to 3.9.0.Final as well

Comment: Hi! Good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!